# Publish project with embedded DB connect with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have a SQL Server CE 3.5 DB which is set to "Embedded" vis a vis Properties.  The database has an associated .edmx file and entity-framework code works when I run it from VS 2010.

The app.config string is the following:

```
 <add name="MapProjectDB2Entities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MapProjectDB.csdl|res://*/MapProjectDB.ssdl|res://*/MapProjectDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MapProjectDB2.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

But when I Publish my project and run it from the one-click deploy folder, the exception is "The Underlying Data Provider Failed to Open".

So I need to somehow connect to my embedded database.  Thanks in advance the google hits are a bit spotty for this one.

I should mention that the DB is member of a library (DLL) project, which is loaded from another project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add the DB to my Exe project.  From there I needed to change the config string to be the following:

The difference is only the |DataDirectory|\ part

```
<add name="MapProjectDB2Entities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MapProjectDB.csdl|res://*/MapProjectDB.ssdl|res://*/MapProjectDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MapProjectDB2.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```